# Create new object in database based on the object name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dbcontext

I am working on a project where I need to create an object based on the object name or the object itself, first I am creating a new object like so:

```
object type = GetInstance(objectName);

public object GetInstance(string strFullyQualifiedName)
    {
        try
        {
            Type t = Type.GetType("RosyMasterDBManagement.Models." + strFullyQualifiedName.Replace("ID", ""));
            if (t != null)
                return Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            foreach (var asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                t = asm.GetType(strFullyQualifiedName);
                if (t != null)
                    return Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

And now I am trying to do something like this:

```
await _context.(Here goes something with the object I guess).AddAsync(type);
```

Is there a way at all to do this and if there is a way how do I fix this?

Comment: You can use reflection to search through the properties of your context. Find the property that is a collection of the same type as the object you are trying to put in it. Then you can get that value from your context, and call your method `AddAsync` on that value.

Comment: How do I get the value from the context based of the PropertyInfo I retrieved?

Comment: In your case it would be `yourPropertyInfo.GetValue(_context)`. Afterwards, you would need to cast it to whatever the type in your code is that has the `AddAsync` method

Comment: I was now able to get the context but there is no `AddAsync` methode available.